# Org-Agenda: Show Weekend Days (only)

Tags: org-mode

I would like to have a custom agenda view in my org agenda, that shows only weekend days.

For example, when I open [m]onth view (M-x org-agenda a v m), I see the current month. I would like to hide the work days and show weekend days only. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interactive function that shows the agenda for the current or upcoming weekend:

```
(defun org-next-weekend-agenda ()
  "Produce an agenda view for the current or upcoming weekend from all files in variable `org-agenda-files'."
  (interactive)
  (let*
      ((day (string-to-number (format-time-string "%w")))
       (offset
    (cond ((zerop day) -1)      ; it's Sunday
          (t (- 6 day))))       ; any other day
       (offset-string
    (cond ((>= offset 0) (concat "+" (number-to-string offset)))
          (t (number-to-string offset)))))
    (org-agenda-list nil offset-string 2)))
```

There may be a way to do this as a custom agenda... but I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the best route it to extend the main org-agenda dispatch rather than the view dispatch which is less powerful. This will allow you to add more commands to the main org-agenda menu. This dispatch is quite customizable through the `org-agenda-custom-commands` variable, which you can customize or set.  This will allow you to add custom commands.  For example for a view of next weekend:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
           '("W" "Weekend"
             ((agenda "" ))
             (
              (org-agenda-overriding-header "WEEKEND")
              (org-agenda-span 2)
              (org-agenda-start-day "saturday")    
              )) t)
```

So then

<kbd>M-x</kbd> org-agenda <kbd>S-w</kbd>

gives you next weekend.  It is quite typical to bind `org-agenda` to <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.  So this becomes <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>.

Comment: This command will show me one weekend. I would like to see multiple weekends, like the ones of the current month or the following four weekends or something like that. Alternatively it would also do if i could just see one weekend and then navigate through weekends via `n` or `p`. Anyways, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Are you asking to display the content for the weekends, but still display the weekdays with no content, or just display the weekend days?

Comment: Just the weekend days. Use case: Schedule Weekend Activities without weekday distractions.